# Merging with various lists

Tags: python

I am tasked to merge the lists into a single one. For example:

```
all_lst = [[2, 7, 10], [0, 4, 6], [3, 11]]
>>> [0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11]
```

I have defined:

```
 def merge(left, right):
     results = []
    while left and right:
        if left[0]< right[0]:
            results.append( left[0])
            left.remove( left[0])
        else:
            results.append( right[0])
            right.remove (right[0])
    results.extend(left)
    results.extend(right)
    return results
```

and

```
def merge_lists(all_lst):
    for i in range( len(all_lst)):
        A = merge(all_lst[i], all_lst[ i+1])
        new = all_lst[i+2:]
        B = merge( list(A), list(new))
    return B
```

However I am given by IDLE:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#162>", line 1, in <module>
    print(merge_lists(all_lst))
  File "<pyshell#161>", line 5, in merge_lists
    B = merge( list(A), list(new))
  File "<pyshell#110>", line 4, in merge
    if left[0]< right[0]:
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < list()
```

I would really appreciate it if you could tell me what's wrong. Thanks~!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flattening a shallow list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to re-invent the weel. Use `chain` from [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html), like this:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> i = [[2, 7, 10], [0, 4, 6], [3, 11]]
>>> sorted(it.chain(*i))
[0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11]
```

The sorted call is required as your result needs to be ordered.

Answer (score 1):

`all_lst` is a list of lists, then, when you do

```
new = all_lst[i+2:]
```

`new` will also be a list of lists (because of list slicing), then when you do:

```
B = merge(A, new)   # cast to list is not necessary, since both are already lists
```

in the line

```
if left[0]< right[0]:
```

you are accessing to the first elements. In the list `A` the first element will be an integer, but in the list `new` (list of lists) the first element will be a **list**. That's why you are getting that error.

**Note:**

- I would recommend you to use a debugger or print statements to see what's happening in your program.

Answer (score 1):

Using [reduce](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#reduce):

```
sorted(reduce(lambda r,x:r+x,all_lst[1:],all_lst[0]))
```

Using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [extend](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```
result = all_lst[0]
[result.extend(i) for i in all_lst[1:]]
print sorted(result)
```